# color formatting a group of cells based on values of one cell inside the group

Tags: excel

I have a table with few "2*3 matrix" like this:

> A1 B1
>
> A2 B2
>
> A3 B3

I want each "matrix" is highlighted if related cell B3 with specific string.

It works if i list all condition

eg:if cell B3 with string "2A",that "matrix" will highlighted.

works:  =OR(A1:B3="2A",A1:B3="2A2",A1:B3="2AT",A1:B3="2AT2")

not works:  =SEARCH("2A",A1:B3,1)   //only B3 will highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Formulas used with conditional formatting need to return only **`TRUE`** or **`FALSE`**.

Function `SEARCH` returns an error if a match isn't found, or a Position Number if a match is found.

Perhaps you could use `ISERROR` to determine if `SEARCH` returns an error (and reverse the results with `NOT`):

```
=NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("1A2b",A1:B3,1)))
```

...returns **TRUE** if the search text is found, or **FALSE** if an error has occurred.

Comment: thx. I try that with my small trick,it works. for reference,OR() should be attached in the front of formula.But,i can't explain that.